# Difference between str() and astype(str)?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I want to save the dataframe df to the .h5 file MainDataFile.h5 :

```
df.to_hdf ("c:/Temp/MainDataFile.h5", "MainData", mode = "w", format = "table", data_columns=['_FirstDayOfPeriod','Category','ChannelId'])
```

and get the following error :

> *** Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> > [dtype->object,items->Index(['Libellé_Article', 'Libellé_segment'], dtype='object')]

If I modifify the column 'Libellé_Article' in this way :

```
df['Libellé_Article'] = str(df['Libellé_Article'])
```

there is no error anymore, whereas I still get the error message when doing :

```
df['Libellé_Article'] = df['Libellé_Article'].astype(str)
```

The problem is that using str() is blowing up my ram.

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an unformatted blob of nonsense.

Comment: Formatting is fixable (done). The question is still unclear, however. Can you reformulate it to contain an actual question? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my browser sent the question before I finished to write it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str(df['Libellé_Article'])` will convert the contents of the entire column in to single string. It will end up with a very big string. And thats the reason for blowing up your RAM

For example

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['A'])
>> df['A']
0    1
1    2
2    3 
Name: A, dtype: int64

>> str(df['A'])
 '0    1\n1    2\n2    3\nName: A, dtype: int64'
>> df['A'].astype(str)
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: object
```

So you should use `.astype(str)` only, if you want to convert your entire column to type string

Comment: Thanks Kathirmani, you are perfectly right ! So the question remains why I get an error message when applying `.astype(str)`. I suspect a special character in the column 'Libellé_Article', but unable to find which so far.

Comment: For that please post some sample data, so that i can try it out locally in my machine

Answer (score 1):

- The difference here is that `.astype(str)` is a method for a Pandas series and `str()` is a function.
- This is why :
  `.astype(str)` will work on series and not on int
  while `str()` will work on both.