# Concatenate year and quarter as string

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I got a Date column in my dataset and I like to create a new column that I will contain values like '2004_1' .This will indicate that the date is in year 2004 and Quarter-1.

I am not able to create it successfully. the code I have used below is giving junk.

```
df['year']=df['Date'].dt.year
df['qtr']=df['Date'].dt.quarter
df['yr_qr'] =str(df['year']) + '_' + str(df['qtr'])
```

I have ensured that Date is datetime64 object and year, qtr are created correctly (int64).

A slice of data is below.

```
   Date     year  qtr       yr_qr
```

0   2002-01-15  2002    1       0 2002\n1 2002\n2 2002\n3 ...

1   2002-01-16  2002    1       0 2002\n1 2002\n2 2002\n3 ...

2   2002-01-17  2002    1       0 2002\n1 2002\n2 2002\n3 ...

Please help.

Comment: `df['year']=str(df['Date'].dt.year).rstrip()`?

Answer (score 0):

I could discover the important difference between str() and astype(str) when applied to a dataframe. str() method will concatenate values from all rows; obviously not what we are looking for. To apply to each field, we should use astype(str)

Hence, the code modified as below fixed it.

```
df['yr_qr'] =df['year'].astype(str) + '_' + df['qtr'].astype(str)
```

Refer the previous question below.

[Difference between str() and astype(str)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095172/difference-between-str-and-astypestr)